# Use awk to list files with spaces in them

Tags: awk

I was doing some experimenting with awk last year. I wrote the following to modify git output:

`git status -s | awk '{printf("\t%s: %s %s\n", FNR, $1, $2)}'`

This outputs something like

```
        1: M "_notes/Digital
        2: M _notes/Perl.md
        3: M "_notes/Tech
        4: M _notes/vim.md
```

It works but chokes when the file has a space in it like in lines 1 and 3 in the above example. Note that I'm on MacOS and these two files are surrounded by apostrophes:

```
'Digital Gardening.md'
'Tech Stuff.md'
```

How can I modify this so it will output files with spaces properly?

Comment: You'll have to [edit] your question show us the input to awk (i.e. the output from `git status -s`) and the output you want from awk for us to help you. So far you've shown us the output you get but not the output you want, nor the input that needs to be parsed to produce that output. Since there's nothing in your script to create double quotes (`"`), those most be present in your input but you say the input uses single quotes (`'`). It's also not obvious why you wouldn't just use `print NR, $0` so it's not clear what is really going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you're just numbering the lines, you can just simply do this instead

```
$ git status -s | nl -s:
```

or, with `awk`

```
$ git status -s | awk '{print NR":",$0}'
```

Comment: Both of these work well. And it looks like I asked an XY question.

Comment: It's not particularly an XY question, it's just missing the key parts that'd make it an adequate question for this forum, e.g. sample input and expected output. I had been hoping I could coach you on how to ask a good question (see [ask]) so you'll be able to do so next time but you didn't respond to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943616/use-awk-to-list-files-with-spaces-in-them#comment111309418_62943616) on how to get there. Ah well....

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk 4:

```sh
git status -s | awk '{printf("\t%s: %s %s\n", FNR, $1, $2)}' FPAT="([^ ]+)|('[^']+')"
```

From its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content):

> The value of FPAT should be a string that provides a regular expression. This regular expression describes the contents of each field.

In the above example, we need the field to be non-space `[^ ]+` or a string that is quoted by `'`: `('[^']+')`

Comment: File names can contain single quotes (`'`) so YMMV with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

`git` command has `-z` option to print a NULL byte instead of new line after each file. You can use `-z` with `RS='\0'` in `gnu-awk`:

```
git status -sz | awk -v RS='\0' '{col1=$1; $1=""; printf "\t%s: %s%s\n", FNR, col1, $0}'
```